# What does struct Snake { int x, y; } snake[225]; mean?

Tags: c++

I have this piece of code but I don't know what it means. If anyone could explain that would be helpful for me. I think this is an array of structs, am I right?

```
struct Snake
{
    int x, y;
} s[225];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right. It's an array of structure `Snake`.

You can store information of multiple `Snake` in there (in your code `225` snake information can be stored as you took size of the `array` as `225`).

For example:

```
s[0].x = any_int_value;
s[0].y = any_int_value;
....
```

There're many other ways to access and assign values. To learn more about array of structure, please check following resources

- [Array of Structures vs. Array within a Structure in C/C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-of-structures-vs-array-within-a-structure-in-c-and-cpp/)
- [C Array of Structures](https://www.javatpoint.com/array-of-structures-in-c)
- [Array of Structures in C](https://overiq.com/c-programming-101/array-of-structures-in-c/)

Comment: You're always welcome. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

> I think this is an array of structs, am I right?

You are right. The name of the class is `Snake`, the name of the array is `s` and the array has 225 elements and the type of the elements is `Snake`.